# Cannot Bind the Socket: error(99, 'Cannot assign requested address')

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, udp

I'm able to ping the computer with IP address `130.203.223.236` from another computer with IP address `130.203.223.228`. But I couldn't create a socket on `130.203.223.228` listening to `130.203.223.236`. It's giving an error

> 99, 'Cannot assign requested address'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import socket

# UDP port details, to send data to AIMSUN
send_host = '130.203.223.236'
send_port = 5002

# Create socket connection to send data to AIMSUN
send_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
send_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
try:
    send_sock.bind((send_host, send_port))
except socket.error as error:
    print('Receive socket', error)
```

Comment: You're trying to bind to the target address. Solution: don't. The bind-address is a local address, not a remote address. Usually the bind-address is 0.0.0.0, and in UDP the client socket isn't usually bound explicitly at all.

Comment: NB 'listening' is a TCP concept. What you are doing here is first binding to a local address, then sending and receiving to and from some remote address. No listening whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to fix that